# how to stop it without using "brake;"? its a guessing play

Tags: python

```
import math
import random
a = math.floor((random.random())*100)
if a%10 != 00:
    c = math.floor(a/10)
    a = a - c*10
    #to make sure the number isnt over 10
attempts = int(input("enter num of attempts"))
att = attempts
for i in range(0,attempts+1,1):
    tr = int(input("try"))
    att = att -1
    if tr == a:
        print("good")
        break;
    else:
        print("no,try again", "you got",att,"more attempts")
        if att == 0:
            print("game over,the num was", (a))
```

the game has random num between 0-10 and you need to insert num of attempst, and then guess what number is it, and you got the amount of attempst you have insert to try guessing the num.

Comment: This is not MatLab., the semicolon after `break` is a typo.

Comment: What's wrong with `break`? You could find another way... but `if... break` is not an unusual way of breaking loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `for` loop by a `while` loop.

This way you have more control, you can use a `found` boolean and loop while it is `False`.

Note also that you have to increment `i` by yourself.

I printed the messages (win/lost) outside of the loop.
It makes the loop code more readable.

I also used `randint()` to choose the random number to guess.
It does all the work without further computation and is also part of the `random` module.

```py
from random import randint

a = randint(1, 10)
attempts = int(input("enter num of attempts"))
att = attempts
found = False
i = 0
while i < attempts and not found:
    i += 1
    att -= 1
    tr = int(input("try"))
    if tr == a:
        found = True
    elif att > 0:
        print("no,try again", "you got", att, "more attempts")
if found:
    print("good")
else:
    print("game over,the num was", (a))
```